# How do I code logging into a site, click a button, and then interact with the next page?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to log into a vendor's site through code, then press a "User Acknowledgement" button on the page that loads after the login page, and then download a file from the third page.

Does anyone have an example for programmatically logging into a page, then interacting with the second page?

I have found plenty of examples that allow me to log into a site via code, but I have not seen anything about interacting with the page after the login (and I am going to fire a button on the second page as a "User Acknowledgement").

The code example I am looking for needs to be for .Net (either C# or VB.Net).

Thanks.

Comment: [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) should make all that possible.

Comment: Fiddler can help you figure out the correct http POST and GET requests to make.

Answer (score 0):

How I've done something similar was to put the handler for the second page in an event handler that runs when the first page is fully loaded.  I was doing only gets, though.

Answer (score 0):

If i understanding you correctly you can use `web browser control` for this so i write a simple example for you:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //navigate to you destination 
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.certiport.com/portal/SSL/Login.aspx");
        }
        bool is_sec_page = false;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!is_sec_page)
            {
                //get page element with id
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Username").InnerText = "username";
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Password").InnerText = "pass";
                //login in to account(fire a login button promagatelly)
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_LoginBtn_c_CommandBtn").InvokeMember("click");
                is_sec_page = true;
            }
            //secound page(if correctly aotanticate
            else
            {
                //intract with sec page elements with theire ids
            }

        }
```